# In the substitution problem from Week 2 of CS50, why should we store "/0" in ciphertext array of this code?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool check_char(string key);
void cipher_function(string plaintext, string argv);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (!check_char(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 unique characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Get plaintext from user
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    // Function to generate and print ciphertext based on plaintext and key
    cipher_function(plaintext, argv[1]);


}

bool check_char(string key)
{
    int length;
    length = strlen(key);

    if (length != 26)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        key[i] = toupper(key[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(key[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (key[i] == key[j])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void cipher_function(string plaintext, string argv)
{
    int length = strlen(plaintext);
    int index;
    char ciphertext[length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (islower(plaintext[i])) // If plaintext character is lowercase
        {
            index = plaintext[i] - 97;
            ciphertext[i] = argv[index];
            if (isupper(ciphertext[i])) // If the ciphertext char for corresponding plaintext is upper, then convert to lower
            {
                ciphertext[i] += 32;
            }
        }
        else if (isupper(plaintext[i])) // If plaintext character is uppercase
        {
            index = plaintext[i] - 65;
            ciphertext[i] = argv[index];
            if (islower(ciphertext[i]))
            {
                ciphertext[i] -= 32;   // If the ciphertext char for corresponding plaintext is lower, then convert to upper
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i]; // To print out non-alpha characters in the plaintext like spaces, numbers etc.
        }
    }
    ciphertext[length] = '\0';
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
}
```

So i tried without storing the /0 (line 92) and only setting the length of the ciphertext array to be equal to the plaintext array (line 65). This resulted in some of the inputs showing a weird symbol with a question mark, at the end of the output.

I read somewhere that we need to store /0 to show the compiler where the string ends. I know this applies to strings, but how exactly does it apply to arrays?

Comment: It is `'\0'` not `'/0'`. It is a nul string terminator, value `0`. In C a `char` array is not a "string" without the terminator, and cannot be passed to string handling functions. Here, `char ciphertext[length + 1];` is being built character by character. Notice the `+1` length to accomodate this terminator. Also, despite the confusion cause by cs50's `string` type, there is no formal string type in C. There are only nul-terminated `char` arrays.

Comment: My bad. So basically a compiler can't figure out the end of a string without the \0? Is that why those weird characters appeared at the end?

Comment: Is *isn't* a string without that terminator. cs50's definition of `string` is plain confusing, and is their own invention that is supposed to help students. But nobody codes like that. Defining something as a `string` does not make it such.

Comment: Re *"a compiler can't figure out the end of a string without the \0?"* The compiler does not figure out strings like that, quite the contrary it will automatically place one *at compilation time* in a definition such as `char name[] = "King Brain";`

Comment: It's not a matter of what the compiler can "figure out", it's how the string-functions work. In this case, you're telling `printf` to print a string by using the `"%s"` format specifier. That means `printf` will print out characters until it sees a NUL terminator. If you don't include that, it will obliviously continue out past the bounds of your `ciphertext`, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), until it finds one or the process gets terminated by the OS for accessing memory it doesn't own.

Comment: Oh....so its because im using strings, which only exist cuz of cs50.h, that i need to include the \0? Would the compiler do it automatically if i were to use the traditional char type as opposed to the string type from cs50?

Comment: Oh thanks a lot yano....that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I think it best if you study the teaching material.

Comment: No. The compiler only adds null terminators automatically when you use string literals. If you're filling in the string dynamically you have to add it in code.

Comment: also sorry to bother u guys but i had one last question....isnt the for loop to capitalize the key redundant here? Cuz we're already converting ciphertext characters if their case doesn't match with the plaintext right?

Comment: Yes, it is. And the `isupper(ciphertext[i])` is also redundant, since all the cyphertext is uppercase.

Comment: It's better practice to use character constants instead of magic numbers (eg, do `- 'a'` instead of `- 97`). Better still, use the [`toupper` and `tolower`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/toupper.3.html) functions to change case.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't apply to arrays, just to arrays of chars that you want to handle with string manipulation functions.  It is just a convention, a strong one that is followed by most of the standard library.  But you can make strings workd differently, reimplementing all the string manipulation functions.

In C a string (a variable length string) is handled by using a fixed length array (array sizes must be defined statically, at compilation time, so normally you dedicate a maximum length storage, and end the string using some convention) to store it's characters.  So we need to have some way to indicate the printing and string manipulation functions where the string ends, so no more processing is to be done.  There are different ways of doing this, but the selected by C designers is to put a special character `\0` (not `/0` which is not a single character, but two in a sequence.) after the last valid character of the string, this is the reason you allocate one more character cell into the array to hold this last `\0` char.